# A question about deleting a node in a linked list

Tags: c, memory-management, struct, linked-list, singly-linked-list

Before calling the free(); function if I don't assign NULL value to the link part of the node that I want to delete, what will be the problem ? I reviewed some codes of deleting nodes in other websites, but I found no assignment of NULL value to the link part. They just called the free(); function. Please reply to remove my confusion. Thank you.

```
struct node
{
 int data;
 struct node * next;
}

struct node * head = NULL; //This is the head node.

/* Here some other functions to create the list */
/* And head node is not going to be NULL here, after creating the list */

void deleteFirstNode()
{
 struct node * temp = head;
 head = temp->next;

 temp->next = NULL;  //my question is in this line, is this line necessary?

 free(temp);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the line

`temp->next = NULL;`

is not necessary. Any data in the node pointed to by `temp` will become invalid as soon as `free` is called, so changing any values inside that node immediately before they become invalid will have no effect.

Comment: But **temp->next** is a pointer to another node (structure). Is this case true for any pointer also (that is stored in heap) ?
Does it matter whether the data stored in heap is pointer or any other data variable ?

Comment: @AstikRoy: It doesn't matter what data the node contains, whether it is a pointer or not. The value of data at the time it is freed by the function `free` (which only happens on the heap) is always irrelevant. The only important thing is that you update the `head` pointer of the linked list before freeing the node, because after `temp` is freed, `temp->next` becomes unreadable. The code you posted does this nicely.

Comment: I belileve it is common in languages with [automatic memory management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)) (such as [C#](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_(programming_language))) to set pointers to NULL when the objects they are referencing are no longer needed, so that the garbage collector can see that the memory can be reclaimed. However, standard C/C++ uses manual memory management, so this does not apply. That may be different for [C++/CLI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI) though, but I assume that you are not using that.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You've removed my confusion. @Andreas_Wenzel

Comment: @AstikRoy: Meanwhile, someone else has answered your question too. You may also want to consider accepting his answer. You can only accept one answer, though. Later, when you have sufficient reputation points, you will also be able to upvote answers, which an be done with more than one answer.

Answer (score 1):

This function can invoke undefined behavior when will be called for an empty list due to these statements

```
struct node * temp = head;
head = temp->next;
```

because in this case `head` is equal to `NULL`.

The function frees the memory occupied by an object of the type `struct node`. So there is no sense to change the deleted object. This statement

```
temp->next = NULL;  //my question is in this line, is this line necessary?
```

is redundant.

It is the same as before deleting the node to write

```
temp->data = INT_MAX;
```

This does not influence on the list.

The function can look like

```
void deleteFirstNode()
{
    if ( head != NULL )
    {
        struct node *temp = head;
        head = head->next;

        free( temp );
    }
}
```

Also it is a bad idea to define function that depend on global variables. In this case you will be unable for example to create more than one list in the program. It is better when the pointer to the head node is passed to the function deleteFirstNode by reference.

In this case the function can look like

```
void deleteFirstNode( struct node **head )
{
    if ( head != NULL )
    {
        struct node *temp = *head;
        *head = ( *head )->next;

        free( temp );
    }
}
```

And the function can be called like

```
deleteFirstNode( &head );
```

Comment: The comments in the code posted by the OP clearly state that it can be assumed that the list is not empty and that `head != NULL`. Therefore, it may not have been worth mentioning the undefined behavior and it may not have been necessary to add the `if` statement that checks for `NULL`. On the other hand, it can be considered bad programming style to make such assumptions without actually verifying that these assumptions are true. So, maybe it was good that you added this check. Also, your advice on getting rid of the global variable was good. Therefore, I am upvoting your answer.